# Why does the polar graph of 1/x form a straight line at the beginning?

Tags: circles, polar-coordinates

When $$r=\frac{1}{\theta}$$ is graphed in polar form, there is a straight line at the beginning. Why does this happen? What is the relationship between $$\frac{1}{x}$$ and circles?

Comment: What do you mean by "straight line at the beginning", we can obviously see, $r\rightarrow\infty$ if $\theta\rightarrow 0$

Comment: When $\theta$ goes to zero, $r$ becomes infinite. the line is a kind of Horizon.

Comment: What there is "at the beginning", i.e. for small values of $\theta,$ is an asymptote – a line that the curve approaches. That line's equation is $y=1. \qquad$

Comment: Also, when $\theta \rightarrow 0$, we get $y\rightarrow 0$ and $r\rightarrow x; So, (r 
 \& x \rightarrow \infty)$

Comment: @Cardinal : No, you get $y\to 1,$ not $y\to0. \qquad$

Comment: $$y = r\sin\theta = \frac{\sin\theta} \theta \to 1 \text{ as } \theta\to0. $$ @Cardinal

Comment: @Michael Hardy, you are right! Thanks.